# Why does the loading file still show even when a page is cached in nextjs 13 app directory /

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

In my next 13 app, I have a /users folder which is a route. Inside the folder I have a `page.tsx` , `loading.tsx` and `layout.tsx` file. The `page.tsx` queries the DB to fetch users data and shows. On first load, the `loading.tsx` file renders briefly before the `page.tsx` file shows. Each time I visit another page e.g `/home` and come back to `/users` the loading component renders first before the `page.tsx` despite the data being cached on that page. I assumed that since the fetched data is cached `loading.tsx` will not need to render everytime I visit `/users`

`/users/page.tsx`

```
export const revalidate=60

const getUsers = async() => {
  ...
  return users
}

const page = async() => {
  const users = await getUsers()

  return (
    <div>
    ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Question: After the initial load, how can I make sure the loading component does not show on further visits to the page while the route is still cached.

PS: When i delete the `loading.tsx` file, the page shows up immediately when visiting again after the first time it loads.

Comment: ...also pondering this. Whether it is or not, it doesn't seem like the right behaviour.